# Problem in installing elasticsearch for Laravel

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, composer-php

When I tried to install Elasticsearch for my Laravel instance using the following command:

```
composer require elasticsearch/elasticsearch
```

I got this error:

> Problem 1
>       - elasticsearch/elasticsearch v7.6.0 requires guzzlehttp/ringphp dev-fork-elasticsearch -> no matching package found.
>       - tamayo/laravel-scout-elastic 5.0.0 requires elasticsearch/elasticsearch ^5.0 -> satisfiable by
>   elasticsearch/elasticsearch[5.0.x-dev].
>       - tamayo/laravel-scout-elastic 5.0.0 requires elasticsearch/elasticsearch ^5.0 -> satisfiable by
>   elasticsearch/elasticsearch[5.0.x-dev].
>       - tamayo/laravel-scout-elastic 5.0.0 requires elasticsearch/elasticsearch ^5.0 -> satisfiable by
>   elasticsearch/elasticsearch[5.0.x-dev].
>       - Can only install one of: elasticsearch/elasticsearch[v7.6.1, 5.0.x-dev].
>       - Installation request for elasticsearch/elasticsearch ^7.6 -> satisfiable by elasticsearch/elasticsearch[v7.6.0, v7.6.1].
>       - Installation request for tamayo/laravel-scout-elastic ^5.0 -> satisfiable by tamayo/laravel-scout-elastic[5.0.0].
>
> Potential causes:
>    - A typo in the package name
>    - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting    see
>   https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more
>   details.
>    - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it
>
> Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for
>   further common problems.
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
>   content.

then I tried to install the package mentioned in the error using the following command:

```
composer require guzzlehttp/ringphp
```

and I got the following warning:

> Package guzzlehttp/ringphp is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No
>   replacement was suggested. Package guzzlehttp/streams is abandoned,
>   you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested

Then I tried to install it again, and I got the same error.

What can I do to address the problem?

Comment: Seems `ringphp` package path is wrong. Please check this https://packagist.org/packages/ezimuel/ringphp for correct installation and official documentation for `ringphp` is https://ringphp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please simply try installing it again - according to Packagist, there is a version 7.6.1 available that does not depend on such packages any more. This is something you can also find on https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/releases